# The way for slice to expend itself in go

Tags: go, slice

I am new to go and now evaluate a demo function about slice with Fibonacci sequence

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fbn(n int) []uint64 {
    fbnSlice := make([]uint64, n)
    fbnSlice[0] = 1
    fbnSlice[1] = 1

    for i := 2; i < n; i++ {
        fbnSlice[i] = fbnSlice[i-1] + fbnSlice[i-2]
    }
    return fbnSlice

}

func main() {
    fnbSlice := fbn(5)
    fmt.Println(fnbSlice)
}
```

It will print "[1 1 2 3 5]"
My doubt is how the slice add it's len to 5，not the 5th num, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```golang
make([]uint64, n)
```

Will make a slice of length `n`, filled with zeros. Hence, `fbn(5)` will produce a slice of length 5.

Comment: @JamesPei I don't know what you mean. The output `[1 1 2 3 5]` has 5 numbers.

Comment: Hello Hymns, thanks for your quick reply. I want to know how the slice extends itself, it seems to me it should use "append" command.

Comment: @JamesPei it doesn't need to extend itself, because it already has the right size when it's created. For example, the result of `make([]uint64, 5)` would be `[0 0 0 0 0]`.